# Unwanted padding added from app.css in Salesforce1 app | How to remove/override style added from app.css?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning, css, lightning-design-system

A padding of 0.75rem has been added to an outer div as shown in the image below in the latest Salesforce1 app. It's affecting the custom styling of the application.

[image: Unwanted padding]

Is it a good idea to override this style or is there any reason why Salesforce has added this?

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in Winter '18 release.
Please find below the screenshot regarding the same:-

[image: Updated CSS by Salesforce in Winter '18]